# htaccess: file access for specific ip only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have create custom form for user to submit the documents. now i want to restrict the access of that folder for others.. only specific ip can view the documents only.

for example:    **docs**  folder contains some images, pdf, and docx files. now i am restricting access for pdf and docx file using .htaccess code .

now as i have restrict the file access directly , the browser is returning **403 error.**

now what i need is only my ip  can access  the pdf and docx.

for example:  my ip is 100.100.100.100 so only i can access the pdf and docx file  directly not others.

```
             is there .htaccess code to allow file access for specific ip?
```

i did try this code.. which block access for my ip as well

```
                Order deny,allow
               Deny from all
                 <Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js)$">
                 Allow from all
                </Files>

                <Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js)$">
                 Allow from 100.100.100.100
                </Files>
```

Comment: Which version of apache do you have? If you want a PHP solution; test for the variable `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: There are many many examples out there on google. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: here is my code i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

Comment: please check my above code.. where am i doing wrong?

Comment: i want to make pdf and docx to be accessable from my ip  while for other i don't want..

Comment: Everything seems right. Are you sure that you are using a correct IP address? Try checking with http://www.whatismyip.com for example. Also try moving Order and Deny directives to Files blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to deny the content from all and then allow from custom IP. See more here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

Comment: And what if someone uses Apache 2.4 or latter?

Comment: it is the same:-)
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html

Comment: Did you even read the page you linked to? _Available in **Apache HTTP Server 2.3** as a compatibility module with previous versions of Apache httpd 2.x. The directives provided by this module have been **deprecated by the new authz refactoring**._

Comment: The authz directive acts like this -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: It was removed after 2.3